# Scanning in MS Access to input data on a form without having to press any keys

Tags: ms-access

I have a database with two tables.  Table 1 is a personnel list with an employee ID#.  Table 2 has a "Scan" field which is input from a barcode scanner on several different forms.  There are calculated fields in Table 2 which use the Mid function to pull certain characters out of the "Scan" field.  I then use calculated fields to turn the pulled string which uses a base32 number system into a Base10 number.  This base 10 number is equal to the employee ID#. I then use VBA to run a code to run a query comparing the tables and open a form if the employee ID from Table 2 does not match the list in Table 1.  I have been trying to use the "On Change" property in a form to make all the above happen.  I currently have the "On Lost Focus" property doing all the things I need it to do, but it requires an extra movement. I am trying to streamline it and have it as soon as I scan into the form it automatically executes everything in the back end and closes the form, returning to a switchboard.  The issue I am having is the scanner does not enter the complete string as a input at once.  It enters each character individually so the On Change is triggered after a single character and causes an issue as there is no data pulled to compare in the tables.  Is there a way to get this to automatically execute after a scan, but only after the scan has input all 18 characters?

Comment: Can scanner be set to send Enter or Tab after scanning so it will advance to another control on form? Focus needs to move to another control for a control's LostFocus or AfterUpdate event to trigger.

Comment: June7 - Thank you so very much for the simple yet effect answer.  I was able to google this and download the instructions in order to make this work.  You are my hero!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have the "On Change" event test how many characters are in the field. Only do something after 18 characters are input.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub txtField_Change()
    
     If (Len(Me.txtField.Text) >= 18) Then

        Debug.Print "Testing 18 Characters Input" 

        'Do a bunch of things here or call another Subroutine

        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo 'Close the form, without saving

    End If
    
    
End Sub
```